# output of group_split needs to be saved as separate dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, csv

I have split my data frame using group_split and further want to save outputs as a separate csv. I am using the following code. I am unable to get those csv. Please help.
Thank you.

```r
library(dplyr)
y<-year_x %>% group_split(Year)
for(i in 1:length(y)) {                            
    write.csv2(get(y[i]),                            
               paste0("D:/newfolder",
                      y[i], 
                      ".csv"),
               row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_split` will not return you name of the year as list name. Use `base::split` instead.

```
y <- split(year_x, year_x$Year)
for(i in seq_along(y)) {                            
  write.csv2(y[[i]], paste0("D:/newfolder/", names(y)[i], ".csv"),row.names = FALSE)
}
```

You could also do this with `purrr::imap`

```
purrr::imap(y, ~write.csv2(.x, paste0("D:/newfolder/", .y, ".csv"),row.names = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `group_map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

year_x %>%
     group_by(year_x) %>%
     group_map(~ write.csv2(.x, file.path("D:/newfolder/", str_c(cur_group(), ".csv")), row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I get this error:
Error in `cur_group()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: @Amar Please check your package version